# preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash 128

Tags: php-7

I try to do this

```
preg_replace("select (.*) from", "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM", $_pagi_sql)
```

but I get the following error

preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in

What I can do?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 0):

You're not using a delimiter (`/`) for your patterns.

`preg_replace("/select (.*) from/", "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM", $_pagi_sql`

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my answer. Try again.

Comment: No problem. In the future I'd tag these sort of questions with `regex` too. You're more likely to get a quick answer there.